# putting external loadbalancer server infront of HA k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, high-availability

the control-plane end-point should point to the loadbalancer server right?

but I can't get authentication from my HAproxy server to communicate with the supposedly initialized clustered.

I'm stuck in a paradox: i must do kube init with an end point to connect other masters to the cluster, to get a stable end point. but since the loadbalancer isn't part of k8s, it won't initiate it.

what is the common practice?
how would i tell my HAproxy server (loadBalancer) to communicate with the not initiated cluster..??

Comment: disable the health checks on the haproxy side?

Comment: Can you refer to this [doc](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/run-the-haproxy-kubernetes-ingress-controller-outside-of-your-kubernetes-cluster) it might be useful for you to resolve the issue also can you provide the documentation or steps which you are following so that we will try to replicate the same and provide you with more detailed response.

Comment: @Sai the problem was the HAproxy was having configuration problems, after a clean reboot, the kubeadm init for the first control plane was successful, but now the certificate he suggests to use on the join other control planes, isn't valid, or having problem with the date/time...

Comment: resolved that. but now i don't understand if I use the load balancer as part of the cluster? because the cluster needs CNI to communicate, and everyone goes to the endpoint which is the balancer...

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin and networking questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions. I am voting to close this question.